# WM_CHAR - incorrect wParam

Tags: winapi, unicode

I have successfully built and run an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program) Win Api application. Next I have added handling for `WM_CHAR` and `WM_SYSCHAR messages`:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            // All painting occurs here, between BeginPaint and EndPaint.

            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1));

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;
    case WM_CHAR:
    case WM_SYSCHAR:
        {
            UINT32 codepoint = (UINT32)wParam;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The only purpose of the above code is to see during debugging a codepoint for the pressed key. According to my language settings I should get the codepoint [261](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/261) after pressing AltGr + a but I get the codepoint 185. I have also built and run an example application which uses `GLFW` library and set a char callback using `glfwSetCharCallback` fucntion. That callback is called with codepoint 261 after pressing AltGr + a. It looks like that my Win Api code has some lacks but after looking at GLFW source code I have no idea why I get a different codepoint in my application. It is not related to handling `WM_KEYDOWN,WM_SYSKEYDOWN,WM_KEUP and WM_SYSKEYUP` messages - I have commented out that code in GLFW and the char callback works fine. Where is the problem ?

Comment: This is what [`WM_CHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-char) has to say: *"The `WM_CHAR` message uses UTF-16 (16-bit Unicode Transformation Format) code units in its `wParam` **if the Unicode version of the `RegisterClass` function was used to register the window class**."* - Can you confirm that your code does?

Comment: Thank you, that was the reason - I haven't use Unicode version of the RegisterClass.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? That would make for a valuable Q&A. Feel free to submit [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: There is already the reproducible example: the link to the microsoft example and my small modification.

Comment: The [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program) doesn't exhibit the issue. It is calling the Unicode version of `RegisterClass()`. Also, a [mcve] must be supplied **in the question itself**.

Comment: Never mind. I made a community wiki.

Comment: @IInspectable you're right, I have made a copy-paste error and my program hasn't contained the following line of the code: ```#define UNICODE```

Comment: The reproducible example added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Unicode version of the `RegisterClass` function(`RegisterClassW`) works.

> The `WM_CHAR` message uses UTF-16 (16-bit Unicode Transformation
> Format) code units in its `wParam` if the Unicode version of the
> `RegisterClass` function was used to register the window class.

UTF-16 will complement code point correctly.